# cannot display hex value in putty correctly

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, putty

I am working on a project using the MCU TM4C123GH6PM and I am getting data from another MCU. So when I am getting the data from MCU#2 I send it to a COM Port. Basically I am sending  frames of that form:

```
header="#", Bytes:0,0,0,0,0,0,62,64, terminator='\0';
```

What putty displays is the following:

```
#>@
```

I don´t understand, why I am not able to display my bytes on putty.

I using this code for getting the data and transmitting it to putty:

```
while (1)
    {
        if (UARTCharsAvail(UART1_BASE)){
            UARTCharPut(UART0_BASE,(unsigned char)UARTCharGet(UART1_BASE)); 

        }
    }
```

I am using baudrate 9600 on MCU#1, MCU#2 and putty. What is the problem?

EDIT: since a raw byte contains 8 bits while putty is ascii based and an ASCII-character has 7 bits. That ´s why I cannot display my bytes. This means that displaying these bytes on putty is **impossible**. **Is my analysis right????**

Comment: Succinctly, you need to *convert* or *encode* your binary value to hexadecimal ASCII characters, and send the resulting string of text.

Comment: you could also try a different terminal application - for instance Real Term (http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) which lets you set the display mode and lets you display binary data as hex.

Answer (score 2):

There probably is no problem. PuTTY is interpreting the bytes as characters, and the numbers in your example (0, 62 and 64) map to something invisible and to `>` and `@`. See any [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

You seem to expect PuTTY to display things in hex, but it doesn't do that, at least not by default. It's meant for human-readable text. You can of course opt to *send* things in ASCII (i.e. convert the single byte `0` to e.g. `"00"` or `"0x00"`), in your MCU application.

To say it clearer, there is no such thing as a "hex value". A value can be *presented* in hex, but that doesn't make the value itself different. The decimal integer 16 and hexadecimal integer 0x10 are the same number, the number, after all. The base in which it's presented is a presentation detail, and you're failing to consider these things which create confusion.

Comment: I know that I have raw bytes. But I thought that these values can be represented as they are.   Putty is ascii-based.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that MCU#2 is not sending the data in ASCII format, but as raw binary. You need to specify if your protocol is either in ASCII format or in binary format, then implement it accordingly.

Putty, being an ASCII-based terminal, is only able to display ASCII.